# How to uninstall an older PHP version from centOS7

Tags: php, linux, centos, laravel-5, centos7

My project is on Laravel 5.2. and as per guide it required php >= 5.5.6 but there was php 5.4 intalled and I had to upgrade php version through YUM,
But now it is giving error "PDO driver not found" and I tried YUM `install php-pdo`
but it's giving error that "there is conflict between php56w-common and php-comon-5.4.16". I am stuck on this point[image]

Comment: try to completely remove php5.4 and reinstall php5.6 - or use software collections

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix can you please tell me exact command for that

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Subscribing to the IUS Community Project Repository

```
cd ~
curl 'https://setup.ius.io/' -o setup-ius.sh
```

Run the script:

```
sudo bash setup-ius.sh
```

Upgrading mod_php with Apache

This section describes the upgrade process for a system using Apache as the web server and mod_php to execute PHP code. If, instead, you are running Nginx and PHP-FPM, skip ahead to the next section.

Begin by removing existing PHP packages. Press y and hit Enter to continue when prompted.

```
sudo yum remove php-cli mod_php php-common
```

Install the new PHP 7 packages from IUS. Again, press y and Enter when prompted.

```
sudo yum install mod_php70u php70u-cli php70u-mysqlnd
```

Finally, restart Apache to load the new version of mod_php:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

You can check on the status of Apache, which is managed by the httpd systemd unit, using systemctl:

```
systemctl status httpd
```

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-7

Answer (score 54):

`yum -y remove php*` to remove all php packages then you can install the 5.6 ones.

Comment: first all of need to get all php first `yum list installed | grep php` and depend on php version you installed, for my case I run `yum remove -y php71*`